# How do you disable the test explorer in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, test-runner, test-explorer

I use ReSharper to run unit tests from within Visual Studio 2012.

Every now and then I accidentally invoke the in-built test explorer by accident when running unit tests, instead of the ReSharper test runner.

How do you disable the test explorer in Visual Studio 2012, so I can not accidentally invoke it?

Comment: Just close the window once using the x button on the top right. It wont show up again unless you open it up via Test->Window->TestExplorer

Answer (score 0):

Go to window -->Reset window layout

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if there is a mechanism to decouple and/or deactivate the built in test runner. Ultimately it depends how you are "accidentally" invoking the built in test runner. As a starting point, you should consider unbinding the keyboard shortcuts.